# MetaplexError: Invalid owner

Tags: javascript, solana, solana-web3js, metaplex

Here is my code,

```
import { Connection, programs } from "@metaplex/js";
const {
  metaplex: { Store, AuctionManager },
  metadata: { Metadata },
  auction: { Auction },
  vault: { Vault },
} = programs;



const publicKey = "Gz3vYbpsB2agTsAwedtvtTkQ1CG9vsioqLW3cNpvZ";
const connection = new Connection("devnet");

// Get the Metadata
const metadata = await Metadata.load(connection, publicKey);
const vault = await Vault.load(connection, publicKey);
```

**Error**
`return new MetaplexError(ErrorCode.ERROR_INVALID_OWNER, 'Invalid owner');`

It works in the case of `Metadata` but not working it's in the case of `Vault` or `Auction`

Comment: this has no rust on it at all

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using one address that is **publicKey** for running two different types of functions which are completely Different. In this case vault pubkey refers to a different data and metadata pubkey refers to a different data. To explain it more `Metadata.load(connection,pubkey)` here pubkey is the metadataPubkey and refers to specific metadata whereas Vault refers to the Auction programs Manager's data. To deep dive, more into it you could go through the js repo code.

**BTW Metaplex-foundation/js repo has been deprecated and soon going to be replaced by Metaplex-foundation/next-js which is in active development**

[image]